# Parsing PHP Multidimensional Array

Tags: php

Here (given below) is some very simple php parsing multidimensional array stuff I am doing. I am just searching for 'highlighting' key and then storing some key value pairs in another array. Is there any better way to achieve this (I mean with respect to performance), rather than have n foreach loops to get to what you want.

```
$json_O=json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true);
     foreach($json_O as $section1=>$items1){
        if($section1==highlighting){
            foreach($items1 as $section2=>$items2){
                    $key=$section2;
                    foreach($items2 as $section3=>$items3){
                        foreach ($items3 as $section4=>$items4){
                            $value=$items4;
                            $found[]=array('Key' => $key, 'Value' => $value);
```

Here is a sample php object I am trying to parse:

```
Array
(
    [responseHeader] => Array
        (
            [status] => 0
            [QTime] => 3
            [params] => Array
                (
                    [indent] => on
                    [start] => 0
                    [q] => russian
                    [fragsize] => 40
                    [hl.fl] => Data
                    [wt] => json
                    [hl] => on
                    [rows] => 8
                )

        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [numFound] => 71199
            [start] => 0
            [docs] => Array
......
......
    [highlighting] => Array
        (
            [114360] => Array
                (
                    [Data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => AMEki has done it better <em>russian</em>...

....
....
```

Two things now: 1)Can I do it quicker? 2)Can I design it better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this seems unneccesary

```
 foreach($json_O as $section1=>$items1){
    if($section1==highlighting){
        foreach($items1 as $section2=>$items2){
```

you could simply do

```
        foreach($json_O['highlighting'] as $section2=>$items2){
```

simplifying the rest is also possible, although this is untested

```
$riter = new RecursiveArrayIterator($json_O['highlighting']);
$riteriter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($riter, RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);
$found = array();
foreach ($riteriter as $key => $value) {
    $key = $riteriter->getSubIterator($riteriter->getDepth() - 2)->key();
    $found[] = compact('key', 'value');
}
```

personally, I would just use the nested foreach loops though. It's very easy to understand, while my creative use of recursive iterators is not.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($json_O['highlighting'] as ... ) {
   ...
}
```

Just because it came from json doesn't mean you CAN'T access it as a normal PHP array, because it **IS** a normal php array now.

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach when you need to get to *each* and *every* item. If you want only `highlighting`, then just access it directly.

```
$higlighting = $json_0['highlighting'];
foreach($highlightis as $Key => $value) {
 //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

some benchmarks shows better performance of `for(;;)` loop rather than `foreach()`.
and of course direct access to array element is quite faster

Comment: idk, he is asking, if he can do quicker)

Comment: well, it's an answer then, until he not clarified his question 8)