# PHP Array multiple keys

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

Heres what I want to do:

```
<?php 
$array = array("array1" => array(), "array2" => array());

function mdparser(){
   for($i = 0;$i < func_num_args();$i++){
   //foreach arguement go 1 child deeper
   return $array["array1"] //if second argument exists ["array2"];    
?>
```

I need this to parse multidimensional arrays independantly , so I can use it on any Multi dimensional array.

Comment: Read about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: that doesnt help unfortunately

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing PHP Multidimensional Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364896/parsing-php-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Its not a duplicate that isnt what im trying to achieve.

Comment: The reference to "variable scope" should help eliminate at least one problem: `$array` doesn't exist in your `mdparser()` function because it is "out of scope"... you also have other issues, such as missing `}`

Comment: its part of a class thats why `$this->array`

Comment: Then show "real" code, not something cobbled together that's syntactically invalid, and with a myriad of other problems

Comment: it sums up what Im trying to achieve what part dont you understand the code is commented, its also part of a class.

Comment: Well to start with, what arguments are you planning on passing to `mdparser()`.... what criteria should `mdparser()` be using to determine what to return? Is it just the highest numbered element in $this->array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still just guessing at what you're trying to achieve

```
$this->myArray = array("key1" => array("key2" => array(1,2,3)));

protected function mdparser(){
   $result = $this->myArray;
   for($i = 0;$i < func_num_args();$i++){
       $result = $result[func_get_arg($i)];
   }
   return $result;
}

$result = this->mdparser('key1', 'key2', 1);
```

PHP >= 5.6 allows variadics to simplify this:

```
protected function mdparser(...$args){
   $result = $this->myArray;
   foreach($args as $arg){
       $result = $result[$arg];
   }
   return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the array to the method when you call it, assuming you are calling it from somewhere where `$array` **is in scope**

Also change the array you are building so you have a known, easily processible index i.e. 0.1.2... and not 'array1', 'array2',....

```
<?php 
$array = array( array(), array() );

function mdparser($array){

   return $array[count($array)-1];
}

$last_array = mdparser($array);
?>
```

This should return the last array within the outer array.

Comment: 1. you haven't included $array in the function arguments. 2. read the comments above and you'll notice it's actually part of a class, though that's really the OPs fault.

Comment: @Styphon Thanks, woops. Re class, I cannot guess what his class looks like so (s)he will have to extrapolate the answer to the actual situation. (s)he seems enphatic that they dont want to give a real piece of code.

Comment: Thanks for trying but it aint working.

Comment: Well like they said to your question, give us half a chance by showing some more realistic code.

Comment: I cannot its a full class with other 3000 Lines of code...

Comment: well just post the fact that its a class and the method in question and any relevant class properties and of course where and how you are calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt matter now ive found a way thanks anyways:

```
    function search_array(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    $arg_num = func_num_args();
     for($i = 0;$i < $arg_num;$i++){
        $arg = $args[$i];
    //foreach arguement go 1 child deeper
    $array = $this->array[$arg];
    $this->array = $array;
     //if second argument exists ["array2"]; 
}
}
```